# Is there a convenient way to search the archlinux aur AND the other repositories from the commandline?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux

I'm always googling for the correct package-name and would really like to set up my system so that if I want to install Midnight Commander, for example I can just type

QUERYCOMMAND midnight commander

and it will perform the necessary search for me...if it isn't in the regular repositories, maybe provide a link to the newest AUR tarball?
Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Yaourt](https://archlinux.fr/yaourt-en). It automatically searches both the repositories and the AUR by default. It also allows you to install the AUR packages just as easily as normal packages.

To install a package you know the name of (either in AUR or repositories):

```
yaourt -S <package name>
```

To search (both name and description) for a package both in AUR and the repositories:

```
yaourt -Ss ANY NUMBER OF KEYWORDS
```

To search and interactively choose which packages to install:

```
yaourt KEYWORDS TO SEARCH FOR
```

The quickest way to install Yaourt would be to run the command:

```
bash <(curl aur.sh) -si package-query yaourt
```

This uses the [aur.sh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Aur.sh) AUR helper to download Yaourt and its dependencies.

---

Using `pacman -Q <package name>` actually just lists programs you already have installed. I don't know why that would be a relevant answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
yay -Slq | fzf --preview 'yay -Si {}' --height=97% --layout=reverse --bind 'enter:execute(yay -Si {} | less)'
```

1. **`yay -Slq`**:

   - `yay`: A command-line utility used as a wrapper for `pacman` in Arch Linux, with added functionality to interact with the Arch User Repository (AUR).
   - `-Slq`: This set of options performs several actions:

     - `-S`: Syncs databases, but when combined with other flags, it modifies its behavior.
     - `-l`: Lists all packages from all enabled repositories and AUR.
     - `-q`: The `-q` flag makes the output quieter, showing only package names without extra information.
2. **Pipe (`|`) to `fzf`**:

   - This pipe sends the output of `yay -Slaq` to `fzf`, a command-line fuzzy finder, which allows interactive searching through the list of package names.
3. **`fzf` Options**:

   - `--preview 'yay -Si {}'`: This option in `fzf` shows a preview window. The command `yay -Si {}` is executed for the currently highlighted package in `fzf`. The `{}` is replaced with the package name, and `yay -Si` displays detailed information about the package.
   - `--height=97%`: Sets the height of the `fzf` interface to 97% of the terminal's height.
   - `--layout=reverse`: This option reverses the layout of the `fzf` interface, placing the input and preview at the top.
   - `--bind 'enter:execute(yay -Si {} | less)'`: Binds the Enter key to execute the `yay -Si {}` command for the selected package. The output is piped into `less`, allowing you to scroll through the detailed package information.

In summary, this command allows you to interactively search through all packages available in the enabled repositories and AUR. When you highlight a package, you can see its detailed information in a preview window, and pressing Enter will open a more detailed view of the package information in `less`, allowing for extended reading and scrolling.

Comment: Can you give some explanation?

Comment: Awesome! Definitely adding this to my aliases

Answer (score 0):

`pacman -Q <package name>`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Querying_package_databases

To search the AUR, you can use a tool like [Yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) to accomplish this.

Once installed, the command would be `yaourt <package name>`.

Comment: For installing from AUR you can look into the helper programs like pacmatic and yaourt, although the Arch way is preferable: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR#Installing_packages

Comment: You missed the rather large "AND" in the title of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Install [pacseek](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacseek) from AUR, it is a TUI application for searching packages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Providing a more simplistic version of [user3110024](https://superuser.com/a/1822480/1843540)'s solution, you could instead go with `yay -Ss [search-term] | less`, then search for your specific package using the `/` key once inside of `less`.

The `yay -Ss` command works similar to the `pacman -Ss` command, in that it searches the arch repos for the search term, with the key difference being that it also includes AUR packages in the search results.

Pipelining it into `less` just makes it easy to scroll around and search text interactively. If you'd rather, you could also use a command like `grep`, but I feel like `less` is the more convenient option here personally.

Important to note is that this method will search both Package Name AND Package Description, but personally I find that useful sometimes when I can't remember the exact name of a package, or when the command is different to the package name.